# Is $k^{2018}+2018$ prime for some positive integer $k$ ? If yes, which $k$ is the smallest?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, puzzle

> Is there a positive integer $k$, such that $k^{2018}+2018$ is prime ? If yes, which $k$ is the smallest ?

According to my calculation, $k$ must be greater than $10^5$ and therefore such a  prime must be a gigantic prime (at least $10^4$ digits). Also, I did not find a reason that there is no such prime (such as forced divisors or algebraic factors).

Comment: Well, obviously even numbers and multiples of 1009 need not apply.  +1.

Comment: Obviously, I do not know how to do this, so I am going to run it on my python program.

Comment: Just at a glance this seems kinda like a 'fermat prime' type question... super difficult to get a good result in.

Comment: Where does this puzzle come from?  Did you make it up yourself?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, because of the year $2018$ I decided to create a prime-puzzle containing this number. And it turned out to have no small solution :)

Comment: @NickGuerrero The numbers created by this expression are big, but nowhere near the Fermat numbers (If $k$ is a moderate number). So, the chances to find such a prime are much better.

Comment: @saulspatz Of course, I cannot rule out that someone else already had this idea (and perhaps already found such a prime).

Comment: @YashJain Of couse, finding such a prime is only feasible with a computer :)

Comment: This is going to take some time, even in Python, which can easily calculate 100!

Comment: @YashJain I used PFGW , which uses a fast multiplication routine based on fourier transformation.

Comment: If there is such a prime $p$ then $p \equiv k^2+1 \pmod{2017}$. Don't know offhand how much that can help cut down the search space, if at all.

Comment: Also, since $1009$ is prime, you'd have $p\equiv k^2\pmod {1009}$. Together with dxiv's observation, this gives $p^2\equiv k^2+2018\pmod{2035153}$

Comment: I just found a probable prime! : $\color \red {k=129\ 735}$

Comment: As you have observed, the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2018}+2018$ is irreducible and there is no prime that divides $f(k)$ for all $k$. So the [Bunyakovsky Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) would imply there exist infinitely-many $k$ for which $k^{2018}+2018$ is prime.

Comment: @Peter $k=129735$ is the smallest, indeed. No solutions up to $10^{5}$.

Comment: Peter, post as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why this question has no answer since comments contain one, but here are couple more values found by brute force search in Maple. Smallest (probable) primes of these form are given by:

$$
k=129735,145563,147165,\dots 
$$

Also the leading coefficient is positive, the polynomial is irreducible (by Eisenstein for example) and values it represents are coprime (by $\gcd(f(2),f(3))=1$ for example). Thus it satisfies conditions for [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture), by which it should represent infinitely many primes.

Bonus: Since we are already in $2019$, here are couple examples for $k^{2019}+2019$:

$$k=16294,36688,42188,\dots$$